# setsockopt throws invalid argument error on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, sockets

main.cpp:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int s;
    s = socket( AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );

    int val = 0;
    socklen_t size = (socklen_t)sizeof(val);
    if ( setsockopt( s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &val, size ) == -1 ) { 
        std::cerr << "Set sock option failed" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Errno: " << errno << std::endl << "Error Message: " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return -1; 
    }   
        
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

results in:

```
Set sock option failed
Errno: 22
Error Message: Invalid argument
```

This same code runs perfectly on linux, but gives the above error on macOS (10.15.7, g++ Apple clang version 12.0.0). Additionally, with other options (SO_DEBUG for example) it completes. What could be causing this?

Comment: I doubt `int val = 0` is a valid output buffer size.

Comment: You are correct. It does run if I change it to a non zero value. Why does this work on linux but not macOS?

Comment: Aftering doing a `setsockopt`, you might want to do a `getsockopt` to see what the value actually got set to.  The setter code is more what you’d call ‘guidelines’ than actual rules.

Comment: Linux might use `max(val, 1024)` in the internals, macOS might refuse invalid sizes.

Comment: According to Linux's man documentation, `0` is not valid for `SO_SNDBUF`: "*`SO_SNDBUF` Sets or gets the maximum socket send buffer in bytes.  The kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping overhead) when it is set using `setsockopt(2)`, and this doubled value is returned by `getsockopt(2)`.  The default value is set by the `/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default` file and the maximum allowed value is set by the `/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max` file.  **The minimum (doubled) value for this option is 2048**.*".

Comment: And why do you want to set it to zero? Most times you want to set it much larger than the default. If you set it to zero you can never send anything, because the conditions required for `send()` not to block can never be satisfied.